# d3 iframe in Wix?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, iframe, velo

I have an existing web portfolio created using Wix and I would like to embed a simple force-directed network graph using d3 that summarizes my skills and interests.

Before I started creating the graph, I decided to quickly test if Wix would display an existing d3 graph in an iframe. I added an HTML iframe and wix and copied in the following code (to one of d3's example visualizations):

```
<iframe sandbox="allow-popups allow-scripts allow-forms allow-same-origin" src="https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/raw/4062045/" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" style="height:600px;" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

The result is an empty iframe. I've heard that Wix doesn't like to play with others. Does d3 not work at all in Wix iframes?